# I have this data set for crimes of a 12 month time period , over 250k rows and i want to predict future crimes by date and location

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science, sklearn-pandas

I have this 250k data set with these features

```
    date_time       FullAddress             call_type priority   lat       long
0   6/14/17 21:54   10 14TH ST\, San Diego\, CA 1151    2.0 32.705449   -117.151870
1   3/29/17 22:24   10 14TH ST\, San Diego\, CA 1016    2.0 32.705449   -117.151870
2   6/3/17 18:04    10 14TH ST\, San Diego\, CA 1016    2.0 32.705449   -117.151870
3   3/17/17 10:57   10 14TH ST\, San Diego\, CA 1151    2.0 32.705449   -117.151870
4   3/3/17 23:45    10 15TH ST\, San Diego\, CA 911P    2.0 32.705722   -117.15035
```

Date and time , full address , lat and long , and call type , and level of the seriousness of the crime. 
I want to predict the time when Future crimes will happen or predict the location it will happen again. How can i make that happen , will i use regression or classification ? i already predicted the priority, but how can i predict the time it will happen or the location ?

I predicted the priority but doesnt really give me anything . I want to predict time and location or either or.

this is some code i have for my priority prediction

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
my_RandomForest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)

my_RandomForest.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predict_fr = my_RandomForest.predict(X_test)
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print(y_predict_fr)
accuracy_fr = accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict_fr)
print(accuracy_fr)

[4. 3. 2. ... 3. 1. 2.]
0.95100761598545
```

Comment: Wasn't this a TV series?

Comment: wait what ? what do you mean ?

Comment: This was the basis of a TV Series (_Person of Interest_, 2011-2016)... excellent show!

Comment: It's more likely you ended up directly fitting a parametric joint distribution p(time, lat, long) that models count of crimes, and get expected counts on a grid of locations and steps of time.

Answer (score 0):

Time - is a sequence and in order to predict a sequence you want to use RNN ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network)) (LSTM for example). A good book for details: [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/36419563_Supervised_Sequence_Labelling_with_Recurrent_Neural_Networks).

If you want to predict location only (without time) given time, type and priority you can drop time column or, preferably, extract new features from the column, such as day of week, and use a regression model ([nn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network) with 2 units on the output). Predicting location coordinates is regression problem because coordinates is a continuous variable.

If you want to predict both then, I think, maybe, you should predict time by rnn and after predict location by regression model.

Depends on the context, maybe it will be more useful if you represent location features by a city district.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

For location, you'll need to create a categorical y variable for a classifier, maybe by converting the lat/long features to a postcode and assigning each postcode an integer (which would be the equivalent of the 'priority').

Comment: but will that be able to predict future crimes in the locations ?

Comment: You'd need to shift the y value ahead one point in time (use df[col].shift()) so that the features of one crime (X) align with the location of the next (target y). Then the classifier will be trying to predict the location of the next crime from the features of the most recent. You should probably also include features that lookback further than just the most recent crime (such as a column that gives the number of crimes in the past week)